# "Sequence contains no matching element " instead of just null

Tags: c#, linq

The `myCollection` contains no element with `Id == 10`:

```
var myVar1 = myCollection.Where(q => q.Id == 10);
```

In the above case the `myVar1` represents just the empty collection.

But why in the following example I get a ***Sequence contains no matching element*** exception instead of just `null` in the `myVar2`?

```
var myVar2 = myCollection.First(q => q.Id == 10);
```

How to explain it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `First()` expects one and only one result to be returned. It isn't meant to handle a one or no results.

You need `FirstOrDefault()` for that.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358452.aspx) if you want the first matching item or null if there are none.

```
var myVar2 = myCollection.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == 10);
```